# Hold references to "used" Intents/PendingIntents, is this a bad thing?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-alarms

I have written a class to manage setting and cancelling alarms (via AlarmManager). To allow for easy cancelling of alarms I have linked the intents that set the alarm to a "name" and I have stored these in a HashMap as follows:

```
private HashMap<String, PendingIntent> alarmIntentsMap = new HashMap<String, PendingIntent>();
```

An example of a method that sets an alarm is:

```
public void AddServiceAlarm(Context context, Intent intent, int type, long triggerAtMillies, long intervalMillies, String name) throws Exception
{
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(type, triggerAtMillies, intervalMillies, pendingIntent);
    alarmIntentsMap.put(name, pendingIntent);

}
```

And the method that cancels an alarm is:

```
public void CancelAlarm(Context context, String name)
{
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntentsMap.get(name));
}
```

These methods use the global:

```
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
```

This seemed like, to me at least, an elegant way to start and cancel alarms in a system. Is storing references to PendingIntents in the map bad? Would this be considered bad practice in android? I am not very experienced with Android and would love to know.

Comment: as long as you're not facing any performance problems, this should be ok. **But** what if the System kills your app? You restart the device or what ever? Then, all the intents will be lost. So there is no way around recreating the Intents anyway.

Comment: Agreed. This is a cache, and that is not necessarily intrinsically bad (so long as it does not get too big). However, it is *only* a cache, and you will need to be able to deal with Android terminating your process.

Comment: Ah thanks guys, I hadn't thought about the fact that the app can be terminated whenever. I'll look into storing the intents in a setup file or something, but that may undo any good this would do. Is the common practice to just remember the intent you used to start an alarm to cancel it?